# How to avoid scan operation in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

**Post table**

```js
{
...otherPostFields,
tags: string[]
}
```

**User table**

```js
{
...otherUserFields,
tags: string[]
}
```

I am trying to make a feed
I am first fetching User to get the tags

I don't want to use `scan` since its very expensive as it goes through all the records in the table.
Any better approach?

Once I have the user tags I use scan operation on Post table

```
      const { tags } = Items[0] as IUser & Pick<CUser, 'tags'>;

      const ExpressionAttributeValues = tags.reduce<Record<string, string>>((acc, tag, index) => {
        acc[`:tags${index}`] = tag;
        return acc;
      }, {});
      const FilterExpression = tags.reduce<string>((acc, _, index) => {
        if (index === 0) return `contains(tags, :tags${index})`;
        return `${acc} OR contains(tags, :tags${index})`;
      }, '');

      // expensive operation
      const { Items: posts } = await client
        .scan({
          TableName: PostsTable.get(),
          FilterExpression,
          Limit: 10,
          ExpressionAttributeValues,
        })
        .promise();
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state the schema of your DynamoDB table nor which information you have before you make a read so it's difficult to help you.

However, to answer your question in short, you are not doing an expensive read as you are setting `Limit=10` which will consume 5 RCU per request. If requests are infrequent (less than 5 times per second) you still stay within DynamoDBs free tier of 25 RCU.

#### Update

> I am trying to make a feed I am first fetching User to get the tags

Why not use a [`Query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) as you are trying to get a single users tag it seems.

> One thing that I noticed is the above query does not return any document when the table has over 100k items. Why is that happening?

This is because DynamoDB only returns up to 1MB per API call, if you require more than 1MB the you must paginate.

*A single Query operation will read up to the maximum number of items set (if using the Limit parameter) or a maximum of 1 MB of data and then apply any filtering to the results using FilterExpression. If LastEvaluatedKey is present in the response, you will need to paginate the result set. For more information, see [Paginating the Results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination) in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide.*

Comment: User Schema https://sourceb.in/fG5AsZhwC7
Post Schema https://sourceb.in/hbdABtAT5r

One thing that I noticed is the above query does not return any document when the table has over 100k items. Why is that happening?

Comment: I read contains and IN operators cannot be used with Query, So I went for a scan.
Also, I am already using a query to get the user tags. Now those user tags can be used to get posts with similar tags as a user. At least one must exist.